# Where to save repeated value (MVC)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC project i have the following jsp forms

```
1)Login
2)View with all groups
3) Clicking to group you will be redirected to student list of this group
4)In student view I can add new student to group
```

My quetion is: after clicking on group i pass group id to controller and save group id in the Model

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudents(@SessionAttribute("admin") final Admins admin,
            @RequestParam(name = "id") final int groupId,
            final Model model) {
        final List<Students> students = studentService.getStudentsByGroupid(groupId);
        model.addAttribute("students", students);
        model.addAttribute("groupId", groupId);
        return "students";
    }
```

When you want to save new user i pass group id as hidden parameter to controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "doCreate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createStudent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("studentData") final Students student,
            final BindingResult bindingResult,
            @RequestParam("groupId") final int groupId,
            Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("groupId", groupId);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("message", bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
            return "create_student";
        }
        final Groups group = groupService.getById(groupId);
        student.setGroupId(group);
        final boolean isSavedSeccessfully = studentService.save(student);
        if (!isSavedSeccessfully) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "No unique login");
            return "create_student";
        }
        return getStudents(admin, groupId, model);
    }
```

But in this case i should to pass group id to each controller that related to student CRUD and in controller save group id in model. How to avoid code dulication in this case? I think about saving group id in session , but as i know, session attributes should be related to user info only

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable and store your object inside it. Use the annotation

```
@SessionAttributes("name")
```

It is fine if you store it in session.

Comment: Thank for response,but i would like to keep user info inside session such as  user object and so on, is there any alternative way?

Comment: I have been doing this thing the same way and I had the exact same doubt as you. But, after analysis I decided to go with session attribute. You can define the scope for which you want that group id to exist.